# How to save this value?

Tags: php, oop

Sorry for my stupid question. I just start learning PHP OOP and I have a lot of questions.

I would like to know which method I should using to store and bring this value.

First:

```
class Car {

    public $carMake;

    public function setMake()
    {
    }

    public function getMake()
    {
        return $this->carMake;
    }
}

$c = new Car();
$c->carMake = "Audi";
echo $c->getMake();
```

Or this one:

```
class Car {

    public $carMake;

    public function setMake($make)
    {
        $this->carMake = $make;
    }

    public function getMake()
    {
        return $this->carMake;
    }
}

$c = new Car();
$c->setMake("BMW");
echo $c->getMake();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the second class.

```
            class Car {

                private $carMake;

                public function setMake($make)
                {
                    $this->carMake = $make;
                }

                public function getMake()
                {
                    return $this->carMake;
                }
            }

            $c = new Car();
            $c->setMake("BMW");
            echo $c->getMake();
```

Although, I recommend making the "carMake" variable private for security reasons. Most times you create variables with OOP they should be private and you should create methods to get/set them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and well served answer to my question!

Answer (score 0):

As it's a public variable, it doesn't really matter, though the second one is better because you can edit the method to control the input.

If you use protected or private variables, you'll have to use the second one anyway.